# PyO3 can't find Python interpreter when using Anaconda

Tags: python, rust, anaconda, conda, pyo3

Consider the following Rust code:

```rust
use pyo3::prelude::*;

fn main() -> PyResult<()>{
    let gil = Python::acquire_gil();
    let py = gil.python();

    let result = py.run("print('it works')", None, None);

    if let Err(ref err) = result {
        println!("{:?}", err);
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

With a "standard" Python installation, this runs fine, and prints `it works`.
I tried running this code with a fresh installation of Anaconda on Windows, and it outputted the following:

```
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'python'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = 'C:\\bug\\target\\debug\\bug.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = 'C:\\Users\\balog\\anaconda3'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = 'C:\\Users\\balog\\anaconda3'
  sys.executable = 'C:\\bug\\target\\debug\\bug.exe'
  sys.prefix = 'C:\\Users\\balog\\anaconda3'
  sys.exec_prefix = 'C:\\Users\\balog\\anaconda3'
  sys.path = [
    'C:\\Users\\balog\\anaconda3\\python38.zip',
    '.\\DLLs',
    '.\\lib',
    'C:\\bug\\target\\debug',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00000e6c (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\debug\bug.exe` (exit code: 1)
```

It seems all of the sys executables are pointing to a wrong location.

Rust environment info:

```
cargo 1.50.0 (f04e7fab7 2021-02-04)
release: 1.50.0
commit-hash: f04e7fab73128592a4063983c302da788bdfaba5
commit-date: 2021-02-04

rustc 1.53.0-nightly (f82664191 2021-03-21)
binary: rustc
commit-hash: f82664191d0e8764b7435b9d72eb0e366b8b1464
commit-date: 2021-03-21
host: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
release: 1.53.0-nightly
LLVM version: 12.0.0

PyO3 version: 0.13.2
```

and this is the output of `conda info -a`:

```
     active environment : base
    active env location : C:\Users\balog\anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\balog\.condarc
 populated config files : 
          conda version : 4.9.2
    conda-build version : 3.20.5
         python version : 3.8.5.final.0
       virtual packages : __cuda=9.1=0
                          __win=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : C:\Users\balog\anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\Users\balog\anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\balog\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\balog\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\balog\anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\balog\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\balog\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.9.2 requests/2.24.0 CPython/3.8.5 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.19041
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False

# conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\Users\balog\anaconda3

sys.version: 3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [...
sys.prefix: C:\Users\balog\anaconda3
sys.executable: C:\Users\balog\anaconda3\python.exe
conda location: C:\Users\balog\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda
conda-build: C:\Users\balog\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-build.exe
conda-convert: C:\Users\balog\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-convert.exe
conda-debug: C:\Users\balog\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-debug.exe
conda-develop: C:\Users\balog\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-develop.exe
conda-env: C:\Users\balog\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-env.exe
conda-index: C:\Users\balog\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-index.exe
conda-inspect: C:\Users\balog\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-inspect.exe
conda-metapackage: C:\Users\balog\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-metapackage.exe
conda-render: C:\Users\balog\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-render.exe
conda-server: C:\Users\balog\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-server.exe
conda-skeleton: C:\Users\balog\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-skeleton.exe
conda-verify: C:\Users\balog\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-verify.exe
user site dirs: 

CIO_TEST: <not set>
CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV: base
CONDA_EXE: C:\Users\balog\anaconda3\condabin\..\Scripts\conda.exe
CONDA_EXES: "C:\Users\balog\anaconda3\condabin\..\Scripts\conda.exe"  
CONDA_PREFIX: C:\Users\balog\anaconda3
CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER: (base) 
CONDA_PYTHON_EXE: C:\Users\balog\anaconda3\python.exe
CONDA_ROOT: C:\Users\balog\anaconda3
CONDA_SHLVL: 1
CURL_CA_BUNDLE: <not set>
HOMEPATH: \Users\balog
PATH: C:\Users\balog\anaconda3;C:\Users\balog\anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\balog\anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\balog\anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\balog\anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\balog\anaconda3\bin;C:\Users\balog\anaconda3;C:\Users\balog\anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\balog\anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\balog\anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\balog\anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\balog\anaconda3\bin;C:\Users\balog\anaconda3\condabin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit;C:\Program Files\pysprint-cli\bin;C:\Users\balog\.cargo\bin;C:\Users\balog\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\balog\anaconda3\python.exe;.
PSMODULEPATH: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE: <not set>
SSL_CERT_FILE: <not set>
```

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong? I've tried researching, but there's not much resources out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't pretend it's a good solution, but I found a workaround. Anaconda sets up the `CONDA_PREFIX` environment variable, and *in my case* it was suitable as `PYTHONHOME`. However, I'm not sure it will work for anyone, and I'd rather want a universal solution to this, so I'll definitely submit an issue to PyO3. I also don't think end users should call unsafe functions themselves.

```rust
use pyo3::ffi;
use pyo3::prelude::*;
use widestring::WideCString;

fn main() -> PyResult<()> {
    if let Some(PYTHONHOME) = std::env::var_os("CONDA_PREFIX") {
        unsafe {
            ffi::Py_SetPythonHome(
                WideCString::from_str(PYTHONHOME.to_str().unwrap())
                    .unwrap()
                    .as_ptr(),
            );
        }
    }

    let gil = Python::acquire_gil();
    let py = gil.python();

    let result = py.run("print('it works')", None, None);

    if let Err(ref err) = result {
        println!("{:?}", err);
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

Related issue: https://github.com/PyO3/pyo3/issues/1554

Comment: Yeah, I think I get what's happening here... so the code takes care of properly detecting configuration from conda or other kinds of virtual environments. It also uses this properly for instructing rustc on how to link to Python. However, linking correctly means you can now embed Python, but it might not necessarily mean that the CPython functions you are calling, specifically `Py_InitializeEx`, are called with the correct configuration too.

Comment: To answer your concern regarding this not being a good fix: the PyO3 code itself does pretty much what you do for the linking, with `CONDA_PREFIX`, so the question is just how do you set it when initializing Python. Other than leveraging `Py_InitializeFromConfig`, I see no better way of doing this than what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into something similar with Miniconda with one of our in-house applications. It does appear they've modified something in the start-up that caused our application to fail at start-up, but against Miniconda only.

To cut a long story short, you'll need to call `Py_SetPath` prior to calling `Py_Initialize` when you start up Python.

See https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/PC/getpathp.c

Comment: The link appears to be dead